# error: python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++

When I try to include python.h library in my code and I get:

```
error: python.h: No such file or directory
```

I tried yum install and I get:

```
'Package python-devel-2.6.6-36.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version'
```

I added `-I/usr/include/python2.6/`  &  `-lpython2.6` to my make file.

nothing helps.

Comment: please find the path with locate or find command and post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my installation the file is called `Python.h` (with capital P). Try to use `#include <Python.h>` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install python-dev dependency.

Comment: From his error message (when trying to install python-devel" it's likely that he already have that installed.